# Connecting a phone microphone to Raspberry Pi using Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I own a Raspberry Pi 4B model and I want to record my voice with the Raspberry Pi. Since I don’t have a Bluetooth microphone or headset (with microphone incorporated), I want to connect my Samsung Galaxy S7’s microphone to the Raspberry Pi through Bluetooth. Is that possible?

Comment: Please edit your question to detail the make / model and OS version of your 'phone - then folk maybe able to help you a bit more...

Comment: Android Samsung S7

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your phone. If it can be connected to Bluetooth as a headset, you should have no problem connecting it to the Pi. If not, there's nothing you can do on the Pi side.

Typically phones don't implement the HSP profile so you're likely out of luck.